# Is it possible for a device to intercept traffic in a non malicious way?

Tags: networking

According to this [link](https://www.fibepcongress.com/single-post/2019/06/11/BARB-commissions-Kantar-Focal-Meter-for-deployment-across-UK-Television-Audience-Measurement-Panel)

> Kantar’s Focal Meter collects data by intercepting web traffic from all devices connected to the home router, preserving respondent privacy by only reporting data from a specified list of BVOD and other online video sites.

So how is it possible for this device which is connected to the home network as a LAN device to intercept the data, and is it possible doing so without re-configuring the router?

To my understanding it doesn't serve as the access point to the router or as the gateway form the router to the internet.

Comment: I hope this is the right community for this question

Comment: It is the right place to ask. It looks like that device would be in between the wan interface of your gateway router and the actual ISP line, however that's being delivered. So all traffic leaving the house would have this data collected

Comment: The quote is either a lie or very insideous. My guess is the former as the latter would throw up warnings when going to any websites.

Comment: @davidgo, what if it's basically just a packet sniffer? Reading that link lead me to believe that this is just collecting survey data. Not inspecting or interfering with actual traffic, but collecting DNS (domain visited & time of day?). Either way, it seems like an invasion if privacy to me...

Comment: "Intercepting web traffic" means (in addition to other things)  it forces traffic on port 443 to be decrypted. They may have meant DNS requests but that is not what is stated and would not work reliably due to caching and DNS over https. My gut tells me they could be tracking data to a given range of IPs which could tell what devices were looking at what services when - this is A LOT easier to implement but that is not intercepting its byte counting on a router. To the extent "all" web data is implied it is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

it uses arp poisoning to 'pretend' to be the gateway. Devices on the network send their outbound requests to this device thinking it is the gateway. The device then forwards to the actual router. The focalmeter can intercept DNS, whitelisted http addresses, and a specific https tracking domain.